# In jmeter is it not possible to rerun the recorded script in chrome or fire fox browser?

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a 'JMeter' script with the help of 'Blazemeter' plug in to the 'Chrome browser'. Then downloaded the 'Jmeter' script and imported it in the 'Jmeter' IDE. Now I want to rerun the 'Downloaded JMeter' script again in 'Chrome or fire fox' browsers. The script is running and showing result in 'Listners' and I am not able to see the execution in 'Chrome or Fire fox' browser.

To view the 'Test script execution' what is the process in Jmeter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) documentation you will have a clear idea, JMeter is a performance testing tool and not the UI automation tool. It supports many protocols. From the documentation -

> Ability to load and performance test many different applications/server/protocol types:
>
> - Web - HTTP, HTTPS (Java, NodeJS, PHP, ASP.NET, …)
> - SOAP / REST Webservices
> - FTP
> - Database via JDBC
> - LDAP
> - Message-oriented middleware (MOM) via JMS
> - Native commands or shell scripts
> - TCP
> - Java Objects

That being said, as it supports many different protocols, it can be used to mimic the end users browser actions that happen over the HTTP protocol [out of many other things]. But remember document also clear that out as below

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

**TL;DR**- In short, JMeter does not invoke the browser by default but mimics the action you recorded using HTTP sampler.

If you want to perform record and playback for simple user actions which actually invokes on the browsers instead of mimicking, you should take a look at **[Selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/)** If you have to invoke the browser using JMeter then have a look at [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)